# Grab the next item in a list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, pyqt, pyqt5

Ok, I want to have team_change be a function that will set the text for the team1_label to the next team_name in the list (in this case, self.team_names[1]). Is there a practical solution?

```
self.team1_label.setText(self.team_names[0])
self.team_change(self.team1_label)

def team_change(label):
    label.setText(self.team_names.nextelement) #this is what I need help on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in an iterator to the function, and have it call `next()` to get the next element from the iterator:

```
self.team_names = iter([...])
self.team1_label.setText(next(self.team_names))
self.team_change(self.team1_label)

def team_change(label):
    try:
        label.setText(next(self.team_names)) # use next to get the next element
    except StopIteration:
        # deal with the case when the
        # list is exausted.
```

Or, if you cannot use an iterator, you can use `list.pop()` with an argument of zero, assuming you want to start at the beginning of the list, and exhaust it:

```
self.team1_label.setText(self.team_names.pop(0))
self.team_change(self.team1_label)

def team_change(label):
    try:
        label.setText(self.team_names.pop(0)) # use list.pop()
    except IndexError:
        # deal with the case when the
        # list is exausted.
```

As you can see, with both methods, you'll have to test for a `StopIteration` error and `IndexError` respectively. I'm not exactly sure what you want to happen when the list is exhausted, so I left this detail up to.

Comment: Thanks! and is there an opposite of next(). like prev()?

Comment: @BUInvent Unfortunately not. When you've called `next()` on an iterator, or removed an element from a list via `.pop()` you cannot get it back. If you want to save the last element however, you could create an instance variable, such as `self.prev`, and set it the item you last removed from your list. You could then use that to access the last element removed from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found a good way of doing this:

```
self.team1_label.setText(self.team_names[0])
self.team_change(self.team1_label)

def team_change(label):
    label.setText(self.team_names[self.team_names.index(label.text())+1])
```

Just thought I'd let everyone know.